# passing an array from javascript to c++

Tags: javascript, c++, arrays, v8, node-gyp

I am trying to pass an array from a node app to an add-on I have build using node-gyp. As performance is a major concern in this case, I am trying to use the most efficient ways to pass and parse the data. The issue I am encountering is passing an array and then converting it from a v8 array to a regular float* . The best solution I could find is:

- Grab the argument `Local<Array> buffer = args[0].As<Array>();`
- Iterate over it using a for loop to extract the data, like so:

  `for(int i=0 ; i < 512 ; i++) bufferArray[i] = buffer->Get(i)->NumberValue();`

Where `bufferArray` is an float array that I instantiated earlier.
Then, I pass `bufferArray` to my c++ library that through a function that accepts a `float*`.

Is there a better solution than this?

Comment: Is there an internal, contiguous array that is wrapped in `Local<Array>`?  If so, then determine if you can get to it.  If so, then pass that address to the C++ function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie hmmm I'm not quite sure what you mean, can you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: Somewhere in `Local<Array>` is an internal buffer that holds the data.  Get to that buffer, and there is no need to call `Get`.  Just pass a pointer to this buffer.

Comment: That's the thing, I can't find how to get it. Do you know how? I searched in [the v8 `Local` docs](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Local.html) and the [v8 `Array` docs](http://izs.me/v8-docs/classv8_1_1Array.html).